# JOIN mysql com 3 tabelas

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, join

Estou com dificuldades em fazer o JOIN entres essas 3 tabelas, preciso exibir informações em uma página de respostas.
Em **usuário** preciso de nome do usuário que resposndeu ao post
EM **post** preciso de titulo, descrição, data e id do usuario postador
E em **resposta** preciso de resposta, data da resposta e do nome do usuario que publicou a resposta.

OBS(Em usuário foi acrescido o campo Foto_usuario)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O SQL que estou tentando está assim

```
SELECT post.id, post.titulo, post.descricao, post.datahora, post.postador, resposta.id_usuario, resposta.resposta, resposta.data, usuario.nome, resposta.id_post, usuario.foto_usuario 
  FROM post 
 INNER JOIN resposta ON resposta.id_post = 10 
 INNER JOIN usuario ON usuario.id = 37 
 WHERE post.id = 10
```

está retornando assim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: olá Gabriel, seu `join` não está certo, um join é uma ligação/relação entre campos de tabelas diferentes, logo fazer um `INNER JOIN resposta ON resposta.id_post = 10` está errado, no lugar do 10 é suposto ter o campo que "liga" post com resposta, deve ser assim `FROM post INNER JOIN resposta ON resposta.id_post = post.id` e mesmo com usuario

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo agora.

Answer (score 0):

Assim como o [Ricardo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/57220/ricardo-pontual) apontou nos comentários, o modo como está fazendo os JOIN está incorreta. Os parâmetros de ligação que devem ser usados são os mesmos que você usaria no WHERE caso optasse por não usar JOIN, ficando assim

```
SELECT post.id, post.titulo, post.descricao, post.datahora, post.postador, resposta.id_usuario, resposta.resposta, resposta.data, usuario.nome, resposta.id_post, usuario.foto_usuario 
FROM post 
INNER JOIN resposta ON resposta.id_post = post.id_post
INNER JOIN usuario ON usuario.id = post.id_usuário
WHERE post.id = 10 AND usuario.id = 37
```

Pode-se dizer que as ligações apenas são passadas da cláusula WHERE para os JOIN, ficando para o WHERE apenas verificações específicas, como o id do post e o id do usuário

Comment: Muito obrigado!